# Scipy, Numpy: Audio classifier,Voice/Speech Activity Detection

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I am writting a program to automatically classify recorded audio phone calls files (wav files) which contain atleast some Human Voice or not (only DTMF, Dialtones, ringtones, noise).

My first approach was implementing simple VAD (voice activity detector) using ZCR (zero crossing rate) & calculating Energy, but both of these paramters confuse DTMF, Dialtones with Voice. This techquie failed so I implemented a trivial method to calculate variance of FFT inbetween 200Hz and 300Hz. My numpy code is as follows

```
wavefft = np.abs(fft(frame))
n = len(frame)
fx = np.arange(0,fs,float(fs)/float(n))
stx = np.where(fx>=200)
stx = stx[0][0]
endx = np.where(fx>=300)
endx = endx[0][0]
return np.sqrt(np.var(wavefft[stx:endx]))/1000
```

This resulted in 60% accuracy.

Next, I tried implementing a machine learning based approach using SVM (Support Vector Machine) and MFCC (Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients). The results were totally incorrect, almost all samples were incorrectly marked. How should one train a SVM with MFCC feature vectors? My rough code using scikit-learn is as follows

```
[samplerate, sample] = wavfile.read ('profiles/noise.wav')
noiseProfile = MFCC(samplerate, sample)
[samplerate, sample] = wavfile.read ('profiles/ring.wav')
ringProfile =  MFCC(samplerate, sample)
[samplerate, sample] = wavfile.read ('profiles/voice.wav')
voiceProfile = MFCC(samplerate, sample)

machineData = []
for noise in noiseProfile:
    machineData.append(noise)

for voice in voiceProfile:
    machineData.append(voice)

dataLabel = []
for i in range(0, len(noiseProfile)):
    dataLabel.append (0)
for i in range(0, len(voiceProfile)):
    dataLabel.append (1)

clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(machineData, dataLabel)
```

I want to know what alternative approach I could implement?

Comment: You might need to tune your SVC parameters or use a different kernel. Is hard to say. You can perform a [grid serch](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#exhaustive-grid-search) to look for the best parameters. I would recommend you to `shuffle` both `machineData` and `dataLabel` (with same indexes) before performing learning.

Comment: @imaluengo Thanks, any idea about alternative approach not using machine learning?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to use scipy/numpy, you might checkout [webrtvad](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad), which is a Python wrapper around Google's excellent [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) Voice Activity Detection code. WebRTC uses Gaussian Mixture Models (GMMs), works well, and is very fast.

Here's an example of how you might use it:

```
import webrtcvad

# audio must be 16 bit PCM, at 8 KHz, 16 KHz or 32 KHz.
def audio_contains_voice(audio, sample_rate, aggressiveness=0, threshold=0.5):
    # Frames must be 10, 20 or 30 ms.
    frame_duration_ms = 30

    # Assuming split_audio is a function that will split audio into
    # frames of the correct size.
    frames = split_audio(audio, sample_rate, frame_duration)

    # aggressiveness tells the VAD how aggressively to filter out non-speech.
    # 0 will have the most false-positives for speech, 3 the least.
    vad = webrtc.Vad(aggressiveness)

    num_voiced = len([f for f in frames if vad.is_voiced(f, sample_rate)])
    return float(num_voiced) / len(frames) > threshold
```